# Pass parameters from block to a JSON endpoint using taxonomy term from URL

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, 9

I've been searching for a solution to being able to pass a taxonomy term on a views block that is on a given page using the term name that is in the URL. I agree with my team that it would be a best practice to have one block that can be placed on multiple nodes to pull relevant data from a JSON endpoint, on another server, rather than have a proliferation of one block for term.

Example endpoint URL remotesite.com/cars -- this would return the JSON result for all cars, while remotesite.com/cars/studebaker would return the JSON result limited to Studebakers.
Example local node URL localsite/cars would list all cars available and would not need a filtered result while localsite/cars/studebaker would need the filtered result. "studebaker" is a term in the car-manufacturers taxonomy.

We are running Drupal 9.2.0 on the local development server, and have JSON:API installed and enabled,Views JSON Source, installed and patched and enabled, as well as Views Taxonomy Term Name Depth installed.

I haven't found in my searches anything similar to what we hope to accomplish. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a better way to do this other than by using Views and related blocks?

Comment: Are these taxonomy pages? Did you try using the term from the URL as a contextual filter?

Comment: These are on basic page content type nodes, not on taxonomy term pages.